# When do EntityManager gets new session?

Tags: jpa

It's generally obvious that EntityManager is holding current session, we can get it using this:

```
Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
```

But I am curious when EntityManager gets the new one.

@edit

```
@PersistenceContext(type = PersistenceContextType.TRANSACTION, unitName = "context")
private EntityManager              em;
```

Comment: Where does `entityManager` come from here?

Comment: import javax.persistence.EntityManager;

Comment: No, that import statement does not *produce* an object of type `EntityManager` - it only imports a class that you now can use without specifying its fully qualified name. I was referring to the `entityManager` object you showed,

Answer (score 0):

According to your code I assume that you are either using Java EE or Spring.

```
@PersistenceContext(type = PersistenceContextType.TRANSACTION, unitName = "context")
private EntityManager em;
```

In that case the EntityManager is bound to the transaction. That means you get a new EntityManager with every new transaction.

The Session and the EntityManager are the same and have the same lifecycle. It's just another name for the same. Session is Hibernate slang and EntityManager JPA.